# Appcelerator Titanium C2DM

Tags: android, push-notification, appcelerator-mobile

Anyone tried out Titanium c2dm for android?I am using  Titanium version 1.8.1 And i want to do small Push notification Using C2DM server.If anyone Implemented help me!Thank U

Comment: i've used parse to accomplish C2DM, check that out. It has support for titanium :)

Comment: can u help me to do push notification for android

Comment: Hai Aadi this my mail ID "srisugans16@gmail.com" help me.Thanks in Advance

Comment: After Getting my mail Id inform me

Comment: https://www.parse.com/ look into this in the meanwhile. I'll send you a mail as soon as I am free

Comment: Aadi for Modules in the project i need to create Titanium mobile module project or else i can simply clone the project

Answer (score 1):

@Sugan.s Titanium has direct access to Urban Airship which supports push notifications to Android, Blackberry, and iOS.  It's the most recommended, and easiest approach to Push notifications within Ti.

As suggested already, Parse is another great resource.

Comment: K thanks Danny but I supposed to do with Google's C2DM server its free of cost right

Comment: C2DM is free to use, but you'll have to pay for a Titanium subscription to use Urban Airship.  You can get an Indie account which gives you access to a bunch of subscription based Ti modules and it's only like $35/month I think.